# How could I solve this error to scrape Twitter with Python?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, twitter, data-science

I'm trying to do a personal project for my portfolio, I would like to scrape the tweets about the president Macron but I get this error with `twitterscrapper`.

```
from twitterscraper import query_tweets
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

begin_date=dt.date(2020,11,18)
end_date=dt.date(2020,11,19)
limit=1000
lang='English'

tweets=query_tweets("#macron",begindate=begin_date,enddate=end_date,limit=limit,lang=lang)
```

Error:

```
TypeError: query_tweets() got an unexpected keyword argument 'begindate'
```

May I know how to solve it?

Comment: Can you see what version of `twitterscraper` you have installed? The latest should be 1.6.1

Comment: It seems no problem in your code. Check the version of `twitterscraper` library.

Comment: Yes, sure I installed the version 0.2.7

Comment: You should update that to 1.6.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is fine, the problem is that you installed the outdated version of `twitterscraper`.

You may update your package by using `pip install twitterscraper --upgrade`

or

`pip install twitterscraper==1.6.1` to ensure it is the latest