# How could I get a dataframe from my twitters srcapping?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, twitter, data-science

I'm trying to do a personal project for my portfolio, I would like to scrape the tweets about the president Macron but I get an empty dataframe when I execute this code(I tried also with other # and date) and I get few connection errors.

```
from twitterscraper import query_tweets
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

begin_date=dt.date(2020,11,18)
end_date=dt.date(2020,11,19)
limit=1000
lang='English'

tweets=query_tweets("#macron",begindate=begin_date,enddate=end_date,limit=limit,lang=lang)
```

Comment: Please provide content of tweets - If this is already empty, the dataframe will be empty too.

Comment: Hello, I tried also with other example and it is not supposed to be empty

Comment: So please give it a try to provide the content/result of `tweets` to us maybe of both the working and the non working. thanks

Comment: Yes sure but I don't get any results it never worked, I tried (#india and #lockdown)

Comment: So your question should not be "How could I get a dataframe from my twitters srcapping?"

It should more be "twitterscraper - Connection errors and no results for query_tweets" and provide error messages as well as an example how to and what is the output of "query_tweets"

Comment: If you look at the GitHub issues for the twitterscraper module, multiple people are saying that it doesn't work right now. You would be better off using the official Twitter API instead of trying to scrape the website, which is against the Terms of Service.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How could I solve this error to scrape Twitter with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64908317/how-could-i-solve-this-error-to-scrape-twitter-with-python)

Comment: I tried with API of twitter I get it it is probably a problem from the library @AndyPiper